# Find the last index of "\" in a string in java

Tags: java, string

Can anyone help me find the LastIndexOf  '\' in a string in java? I wrote the code as:

```
int i = app.lastIndexOf('\');
```

`app` is my string, but there is a error as "Invalid character constant". I tried using double quotes but still no use. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `\` character is used to escape other characters, in order to print special characters.

For example, `'\n'` is the "newline" character, `'\t'` is the "tab" character, `'\''` is the literal `'`, etc.

In order to use a `\` in a string, you have to escape it: `\\`.

Use `app.lastIndexOf('\\');`

Answer (score 7):

You have to escape `\` as `\\` in java Strings.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape backslashes in `String` or `char` literals:

```
app.lastIndexOf('\\');
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `app.lastIndexOf("\\");`

Answer (score 3):

Since backslash is used as an escape character, to get a literal backslash you type two.

```
myString.lastIndexOf("\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

use `\\` instead of `\`, you need to "escape" the special character \'s meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the slash with another slash: `lastIndexOf('\\')`.

Answer (score 0):

**Input:** We are speaking here  but we need,<1> <12/> find last closing bracket /> eat /> this not required!!!

**Output:** We are speaking here  but we need,<1> <12/> find last closing bracket /> eat />

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myStr = "We are speaking here <as /> but we need,<1> <12/> find last closing bracket /> eat /> this not required!!!";
    String myFinalString = myStr.substring(0, myStr.lastIndexOf("/>")+2);
    System.out.println(myFinalString);
    
  }
}
```